# Azure ARM Template, assign multiple roles to managed identity in Automation Account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-rbac

I try to build an ARM Template to create Automation Account with System Managed Identity, and in the same template add role assignment on the Subscription level to that System Managed Identity. The code I use is:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "AutomationAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Automation account name"
            }
        },
        "AutomationAccountProductTag": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Automation account Product tag"
            }
        },
        "AutomationAccountOwnerTag": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Automation account Owner tag"
            }
        },
        "WindowsRunbookName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Runbook name for Windows instances"
            }
        },
        "RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "name": "StorageQueueDataContributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '974c5e8b-45b9-4653-ba55-5f855dd0fb88')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Contributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "StorageBlobDataContributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "VirtualMachineContributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '9980e02c-c2be-4d73-94e8-173b1dc7cf3c')]"
                }
                
                
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "WindowsRunbookURL": "https://infraawsssmagentinstall.blob.core.windows.net/awsssmagentfiles/Runbook_install_ssm_windows.ps1",
        "LinuxRunbookURL": "",
        "RunbookRuntime": "5.1"

    },
    "resources": [
        // create automation account //
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-06-22",
            "name": "[parameters('AutomationAccountName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "Product": "[parameters('AutomationAccountProductTag')]",
                "Owner": "[parameters('AutomationAccountOwnerTag')]"
            },
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Basic"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].name, '_' , guid(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].name)) ]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "RolesCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "outer"
                },
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                         {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
                            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01-preview",                            
                            "name": "[concat( parameters('AutomationAccountName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', guid(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].name))]",
                            "properties": {
                                "roleDefinitionId": "[parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].role]",
                                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('AutomationAccountName')), '2021-06-22', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
                            }                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }


        // assigne roles to created managed identity from automation account
       
        
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

It is adding the role but only for that Automation Account like in picture below:

[image: role assignment which I get]

And what I need is:

[image: role assignment which I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tested your code in my environment and it gave me the same output as below:**

[image]

**Solution:**

You have to use `"type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"` instead of `"type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/providers/roleAssignments"`. Also in Nested template you have to add  `"subscriptionId":"yoursubID"` & `"location": "any location"`.

**After you have made the above changes your Template will be like below:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "AutomationAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Automation account name"
            },
            "defaultValue": "ansumantestautomation"
        },
        "AutomationAccountProductTag": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Automation account Product tag"
            },
            "defaultValue":"Test"
        },
        "AutomationAccountOwnerTag": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Automation account Owner tag"
            },
            "defaultValue":"Ansuman"
        },
        "RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "name": "StorageQueueDataContributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '974c5e8b-45b9-4653-ba55-5f855dd0fb88')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Contributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "StorageBlobDataContributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "VirtualMachineContributor",
                    "role": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '9980e02c-c2be-4d73-94e8-173b1dc7cf3c')]"
                }
                
                
            ]
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        // create automation account //
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-06-22",
            "name": "[parameters('AutomationAccountName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {
                "Product": "[parameters('AutomationAccountProductTag')]",
                "Owner": "[parameters('AutomationAccountOwnerTag')]"
            },
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Basic"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "subscriptionId":"94xxx4068-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-e00a8xxxx59b",
            "location": "East US",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].name, '_' , guid(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].name)) ]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "RolesCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn":[ 
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('AutomationAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "outer"
                },
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                         {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",                            
                            "name": "[guid(parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].name)]",
                            "properties": {
                                "roleDefinitionId": "[parameters('RolesToAssignForMangedIdentity')[copyIndex()].role]",
                                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('AutomationAccountName')), '2021-06-22', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
                            }                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }


        // assigne roles to created managed identity from automation account
       
        
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** While using the above Template you have to give the `SubscriptionId` instead of using `[subscription().id]` otherwise it will error in finding the subscription.